# How can I extract GUID's from Dictionary stored in JSON field in SQL?

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table:

| Test_ID | Test_JSON |
| --- | --- |
| some uniqueidentifer | see below |
| some uniqueidentifier | see below |

The Test_JSON structure is as follows:

```
{
    "LaneIds": {
        "1": "a5a8ff96-0291-4ef9-890a-57c1874398bc",
        "2": "7a698a8b-934b-4a57-99c7-29a200d87877",
        "3": "aa30906d-e859-40a8-aedd-ae8ae10d0ae1",
        "4": "ccb05b71-a65a-4db7-b7c9-b4b7251150c7",
        "5": "c10593a9-06c3-49e4-bf4e-9d1c5ece98d4",
        "6": "6eeb9c85-f3ac-44cb-be74-f2d7554ea8d3",
        "7": "1226abb3-58c3-4b1e-844f-f2643d874490",
        "8": "7256ce43-014a-4dd6-a072-f8de2c373688"
    },
    "SomeOtherID": "b9d75ef9-b68d-46ef-9d34-3f5e99f448e2",
    "SomeOtherProperty": 12345
}
```

I need to get all lane IDs in a comma separated list for all Test_IDs. So my final output needs to be like this:

| Test_ID | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| some uniqueidentifier | "a5a8ff96-0291-4ef9-890a-57c1874398bc, 7a698a8b-934b-4a57-99c7-29a200d87877, aa30906d-e859-40a8-aedd-ae8ae10d0ae1, etc." |
| next test_id | lane_ids |

What is the best way to do this using SQL/T-SQL?

I am able to get the LaneIds using JSON_QUERY() but I specifically need to drop the ints in the key field and only return the GUIDs in a comma separated list.

Comment: Have you had a look at `OPENJSON`?

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned you're already using `JSON_QUERY()`, I'm guessing the problem is with the definition of your JSON path. Have you tried the following:
`JSON_QUERY(Test_JSON, '$.LaneIds[*]')`? This would query the column you showed as JSON, look for the key `LaneIds` and get all values from within that key.

Answer (score 0):

This should get your values in all their denormalized goodness:

```sql
declare @json nvarchar(max) = N'
{
    "LaneIds": {
        "1": "a5a8ff96-0291-4ef9-890a-57c1874398bc",
        "2": "7a698a8b-934b-4a57-99c7-29a200d87877",
        "3": "aa30906d-e859-40a8-aedd-ae8ae10d0ae1",
        "4": "ccb05b71-a65a-4db7-b7c9-b4b7251150c7",
        "5": "c10593a9-06c3-49e4-bf4e-9d1c5ece98d4",
        "6": "6eeb9c85-f3ac-44cb-be74-f2d7554ea8d3",
        "7": "1226abb3-58c3-4b1e-844f-f2643d874490",
        "8": "7256ce43-014a-4dd6-a072-f8de2c373688"
    },
    "SomeOtherID": "b9d75ef9-b68d-46ef-9d34-3f5e99f448e2",
    "SomeOtherProperty": 12345
}'

select string_agg(keyData, ',')  WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY keyData) AS IDs
  ,     string_agg(x.value, ',')  WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY keyData) AS guids
from openjson(@json, '$.LaneIds') x
cross apply (
    select cast(x.[key] AS INT) AS keyData
  ) kd
```